# Error while Calling Wcf restful service in mvc3?

Tags: html

Following is OperationContract in IService1 :

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetStates",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  List<string> GetStates();

Implementation of method GetStates in Service1 class :

public List<string> GetStates()
        {
            DB_MVCEntities db = new DB_MVCEntities();
           // string temp = CountryName.Country;

            string temp = "india";

            var CountryId = (from n in db.tblCountries
                             where n.Country == temp
                             select new { n.Cid }).Single();


            int ii = CountryId.Cid;

            // int ii =  (ObjectQuery<Int32>)CountryId;

            // object oo = CountryId;

            //int countryId = Convert.ToInt32(CountryId);

            var StateResult = (from n in db.tblStates
                               where n.Cid == CountryId.Cid
                               select n.StateName).ToList();

            List<string> aaa = new List<string>();

            foreach (object o in StateResult)
            {
                string t = o.ToString();
                aaa.Add(o.ToString());

            }

            return aaa;
        }
```

In above method i am taking state list from database using entity framework. when i am executing wcf service on browser it is working fine.means i am getting following output

output Of above Service is as follows:

```
["MH","AP"]


Code for consuming it in MVC3, Register.csheml file:

 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Country").change(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:1264/Service1.svc/GetStates',
                type: 'GET',

                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#State option').remove();
                    $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                        var optionTag = $('<option></option>');
                        $(optionTag).text(val.toString());

                        $('#State').append(optionTag);
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("bye..countryes.");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I am getting following output when Change event occurs of Country:
control is not going in Success method.

On success i am binding state list to state dropdown list.

But i am unable to get json data in mvc3.

```
bye..countryes.

What was the error?
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: is there a reason why you are using WCF service in MVC instead of returning a json result? it would be much simpler and typically what you'd do for this task.

Comment: Why are you specifying contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ... are you sending JSON data to Server?

Comment: C.Hazelton: I am using wcf service because i have to access it in mobile app also.

Comment: Guanxi: I am taking json data from wcf service